# Apache Not Redirecting Non-WWW to WWW HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have a site, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), that I can't visit without entering the www. Using an Apache Virtual Host, I'm trying to make it so if non-www is entered, it's automatically redirected to www.

If I try going to http://www.example.com, it redirects to https://www.example.com and works

If I try going to https://www.example.com, it also works.

However, the problem is:

If I enter http://example.com, it redirects to https://example.com and says:

```
This site can’t be reached Check if there is a typo in example.com.
If spelling is correct, try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

I get the same message if I try going to https://example.com

The problem is my site only works with "www." On non-www, how can I force www.? I was trying the following to no avail:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public/

    # Force non-www to www in HTTPS.
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is an issue with Apache. It's more likely that your authoritative DNS simply doesn't have an entry for the non-WWW version of your web site. For instance, `nslookup www.example.com` will return the IP address of your server. If you do `nslookup example.com` it should also return the IP address of your server; if it doesn't, fix that first.

Comment: That was it! It had nothing to do with my Apache Virtual Host, but the DNS instead. After I added an A record pointing to example.com, everything worked. The redirect in my virtual host was able to redirect non-WWW to WWW and SSL. Great answer. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @tsc_chazz, when you mean IP, do you mean the `localhost IP(127.0.0.1)` or my `public IP of my router`?  Because when I `nslookup www.example.com ==> 192.64.119.109, which is namecheap's IP` and `nslookup example.com ==> 127.0.0.1` not even my public IP. Thank you plse

Comment: There are three possibilities here depending on which name server you're talking about. For your site to be visible to the world, your public address - the external address of your router - has to be set in your public authoritative DNS - you said namecheap.com? For your site to be visible to your inhouse network, its internal IP - likely 192.168.0.something - should be set in your router's local names list. And the machine itself can have the site name in its `hostnames` or `hosts` file that returns `127.0.0.1`.